# react js send object to node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I send the object to the backend (Node js) when API call, but I check objects using console log. I checked using POSTMAN. When I checked POSTMAN, it worked very well, but I try to pass an object in the frontend (react js) it is shown as undefined.

```
  getnotification(){
  const userdetails={
  userid:"1235",
  username:this.state.name
  }
  axios.get('http://localhost:4000/notification/',userdetails)
  .then((res)=>{ this.setState((cur) => ({ ...cur, notification: res.data.reverse() }));

  })
}
```

Comment: in JavaScript you should name the variables and functions with camelCase (e.g. getNotification, userDetails). See more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to `[POST]`, you need to use `axios.post(url, body)`.

Following are the possible method signatures for axios.

```
axios.request(config)

axios.get(url[, config])

axios.delete(url[, config])

axios.head(url[, config])

axios.options(url[, config])

axios.post(url[, data[, config]])

axios.put(url[, data[, config]])

axios.patch(url[, data[, config]])
```

Read more https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro/

Comment: no.I want to use the get method. but I faced for that issue when some time  post and patch methods.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the "{}". You can do something like this:

```
const userDetails = {
      userid:'1235',
      username:this.state.name
    }
axios.get('/user', {
    params: userDetails
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
  .then(function () {
    // always executed
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the async / await syntax instead of the callback function, but it's not supported by all browsers. And you can add error handling to the async function in simple ways.

```js
async getNotification() {
        const userDetails = {
            userid: "1235",
            username: this.state.name
        }

        try {
            const res = axios.get('http://localhost:4000/notification/', userDetails)
            this.setState((cur) => ({...cur, notification: res.data.reverse()}));
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
async getNotification() {
        const userDetails = {
            userid: "1235",
            username: this.state.name
        }

        try {
            const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/notification/', userDetails)
            this.setState((cur) => ({...cur, notification: res.data.reverse()}));
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).